# Installing 15" deep wall cabinets on a 14" deep soffit

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, soffit

I'm remodeling my kitchen which has a soffit/bulkhead that is 14" deep.  I've been looking at ikea cabinets but all of their wall cabinets are 15" deep.

Now, I understand the mechanics of hanging the cabinets should work out fine, but what I'm not sure how to make the 1" overhang look natural.  I'm thinking of just getting a decorative trim of some type and running it along the top to kinda hide the overhang.

Anyone have any experience with this or recommendations?  Thanks

Comment: Yes making up trim would be best way.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Pick one or add one to your style and enjoy .May be post pics after they are up and more pointers could be sent. Or build wall out to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I'm picturing it, there really shouldn't be a problem. Reveals are common in all kinds of woodworking.

The only bad possibility is that the soffit is noticeably out of level, in which case you'd want a strip of scribe (3/4 x 1/4 strip) to hide the variable gap.

Comment: Yes, reveals are common in all kinds of woodworking, but every one I have ever seen in a kitchen is a nightmare to keep clean. Kitchens are not the place to add superfluous horizontal surfaces that you cannot reach without getting on a ladder...

Answer (score 2):

If the cabinets are deeper than the soffit, you have a "shelf" above the cabinets then. That would collect dust and cooking grime and be a pain to clean IMHO, let alone promote a spot for spider webs and the like. I would add a couple of sheets of Sheetrock on top the soffit wall, tape and cover it and make it all flush.

Comment: I considered that, but the drywall at thr face of my soffit is nearly an inch thick already.  Also, theres a bit of variation in depth that might be obvious if i attempt to make the face of the soffit flush with the cabinet facr

Comment: Wow, 1" thick is an issue, I agree. maybe remove that drywall and start over fresh? Otherwise, I would put a 45 degree chamfer trim on these do that it's not a horizontal surface.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with Ikea cabinets so I built out the soffit. I don't recall what the dimensions of my old cabinets were but as you can see a 2"x2" and 1/2" drywall gave me the correct overhang. I didn't use drywall on the bottom I just screwed the corner bead on and mudded it into the old soffit, even if it cracks at the joint with the old soffit it won't be visible.

If I had to do it over again I would have removed the soffit and put in taller cabinets but that's because I would have liked the extra cabinet space. 
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow. That came out great.  I actually think you're right about removing the soffit.  Thats what we're going to do.  Im the end its the same amount of drywall finishing work to extend it out as remove it, then it's a more mosern look. Thanks

Comment: Just be aware that some soffits are built to actually hide existing ducting.

Comment: @Aloysius Defenestrate - Good point, on my first house we removed the soffit and the vent stack from the kitchen sink was exposed. Fortunately it was inside the cabinet and we painted it to match the inside of the cabinet. Before totally removing the soffit knock a few holes in the drywall to see if there's anything hidden.

Answer (score 0):

We took the sheet rock down and built the soffit out to match the cabinet edge. It was a it of work, but totally worth it.